# Flutter Divider is the wrong colour

Tags: flutter

I want to use the Divider widget but for some reason the colour is coming out wrong. Notice now both views in the column use Colors.red, but the Divider comes out faded. What is going on here?

```
Widget buildSpacer() {
  return Column(
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 16.0, left: 16, right: 16),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child:
                    Container(color: Colors.red, height: 1)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(height: 3),
      Divider(height: 1, indent: 16, color: Colors.red, endIndent: 16, ),
    ],
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe this is only the case in emulators for some reason. Is this screenshot from a real device?

Comment: No it's from an emulator! I will try a real device

Comment: I believe flutter adds some sort of overlay/shadow to certain widgets to indicate elevation/hierarchy. This may explain why the custom container has the normal red color while the red of the `Divider` widget has a darker opacity/shadow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the default thickness is 0 (??)

If you set it to 1, they look the same

```
  Divider(thickness: 1, color: Colors.red)
```